# Cs50 pset4 filter grayscale round function problem

Tags: c, filter, rounding, cs50, grayscale

I'm working on cs50 pset4 filter(less comfortable)grayscale and I have to round the numbers if they are decimals. But for some reason, check50 prints this:

```
:( grayscale correctly filters single pixel without whole number average
    expected "28 28 28\n", not "27 27 27\n"

:( grayscale correctly filters more complex 3x3 image
    expected "20 20 20\n50 5...", not "20 20 20\n50 5..."

:( grayscale correctly filters 4x4 image
    expected "20 20 20\n50 5...", not "20 20 20\n50 5..."
```

These are just the sad faces. This is my code:

```c
void grayscale(int height, int width, RGBTRIPLE image[height][width])
{
    for(int j = 0; j < width; j++)
        for(int i = 0; i < height; i ++) {
            double av = (image[i][j].rgbtGreen + image[i][j].rgbtRed + image[i][j].rgbtBlue)/3;
            int average = round(av);
            image[i][j].rgbtGreen = average;
            image[i][j].rgbtRed = average;
            image[i][j].rgbtBlue = average;
        }
}
```

The round function is here:

```c
 int average = round(av);
```

But according to check50, it isn't working. Please help me figure it out. The only suspicion I have is that I'm new to c so I might have a problem in my function. I tried googling it but nothing makes sense. I do have the

```c
 #include<math.h>
```

part in my code, just above the part I'm showing you.

Thanks,
Lost in code :)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It seems the result of division

```
(image[i][j].rgbtGreen + image[i][j].rgbtRed + image[i][j].rgbtBlue)/3
```

is truncated because all of the members are integers.

Try

```
(image[i][j].rgbtGreen + image[i][j].rgbtRed + image[i][j].rgbtBlue)/3.0
```

(Use `3.0` instead of `3`

Answer (score 1):

Instead of using double data type use float

```
float av = (image[i][j].rgbtGreen + image[i][j].rgbtRed + image[i][j].rgbtBlue)/3.0
```

And use 3.0 because it could be in some cases your value is in whole number so it will not round to nearest integer